# Sliding Panel Reveal

Tags: jquery, panel

I have already made a sliding panel with simple jQuery, but it is not exactly what I wanted.

What I want, is literally [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/), but only the panel that appears when you click "Reveal". Right now, my panel does the "Overlay" command, which I do not want. 
I tried to extract the code from the website above, but it's a mess.

I would be really grateful if any of you could come up with a sliding panel "Reveal". Preferably using jQuery.

Thank you in advance!

This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show_menu').on('click' , function() {
        $('div.panel').animate({
            'width' : 'show'} ,500,
            function() {
                $('div.home').fadeIn(400);
        });
    });

    $('span.close').on('click' , function() {
        $('div.home').fadeOut(400 , function() {
            $('div.panel').animate({
                'width':'hide'}, 500);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you are using? The documentation says that the default is 'Reveal' and if you look in the options it shows the tags needed for display. Perhaps read the getting started page.

Comment: I added my coding into the original post. And the code on the website above is for jQuery Mobile, not normal jQuery. I'm not sure if you can use a mobile plugin for desktop pc viewing, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is late but for anyone stopping by, here is a [good](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-responsive/) starting point for jQuery Mobile and "Revealing" panels.

There are examples for both a right and left sliding panel and the source is readily available.